# How to add the private one-to-one chat using pubnub chatengine?

Tags: javascript, chat, pubnub

Actually,

1. I created chat app with chat-engine of PubNub but I am unable to implement private chat of two users on the same channel. This means I have one admin and multiple other users so they can chat with admin and admin can chat with other users but, one user and admin chat should not visible to other users of same channel i.e. private chat I want to implement between two users of the same channel.
   So please anyone references or sample private chat source code with chat engine.
2. Second issue is displaying profile pic with gr

avatar plugging of PubNub, this is also I am unable to display it. please share this one also.

This is my Javascript file:

```
        //create a new instance of ChatEngine
        ChatEngine = ChatEngineCore.create({
            publishKey: key
            subscribeKey: key
        },{ debug: true});

        // create a bucket to store our ChatEngine Chat object
        let myChat;

        // create a bucket to store 
        let me;

        // these function is used for typing indicator
        let sendmsg = function () {};
        let keypress = function () {};

        // create an optional config object to increase the default 
            timeout from 1000ms
        let typingconfig = { timeout: 1000 };

        // compile handlebars templates and store them for use later
        let peopleTemplate = Handlebars.compile($("#person- 
           template").html());
     let meTemplate = Handlebars.compile($("#message-template").html());
    let userTemplate = Handlebars.compile($("#message-response- 
           template").html());

        let searchconfig = { prop: 'state.full', caseSensitive: false }
        // this is our main function that starts our chat app
        const init = () => {
        ChatEngine.connect ('email', { username: 'name', full:'K' },
        'auth-key');

        // when ChatEngine is booted, it returns your new User as 
          `data.me`
        here my function is called by the pubnub

        ChatEngine.on('$.ready', function(data) {
        // store my new user as `me`
        me = data.me;
        //create a new ChatEngine Chat and I am connecting to chatenging
       using this option.
        myChat = new ChatEngine.Chat('chat-engine-server',true);      

        // here i am updating the the state of the user
        me.update(
        {
         full:'John Doe', 
         username: 'John',
         uuid: 'johndoe@gmail.com'
        });
        //starting private chat logic
        // this is what I wrote the code that use to create the privat 
         chat 

       myChat.invite(' invited email');

        me.direct.on('$.invite', (payload) => {
        console.log("invited user");    
        let secretChat = new ChatEngine.Chat(payload.data.channel);            
        document.getElementById("punlicLog").style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById("privateLog").style.display = 'inline';
        document.getElementById("message-to-send").style.display='none';
        document.getElementById("private-message-to-send").
               style.display='inline';            
        here I am sending message to this payload
        secretChat.on('message', (payload) => {
          console.log(payload);
      // using this methd i am rendering private message
          privaterenderMessage(payload);
          });            
          //$('#privateLog').append("Now you are in a Private Chat with " 
          + globalUsr );            

       // this is take the message from the input box to send
        $("#privateMessage").keypress(function (event) {
        if (event.which == 13) {
        secretChat.emit('message', {
        text: $('#privateMessage').val()
         });
        $("#privateMessage").val('');
        event.preventDefault();
        }
        }); });

         //ending private chat message

        // this part belong to the pic
        console.log("before gravator'''''''''''''''''': ")  
        user = new ChatEngine.User(me.state.username, {email: 
         me.state.uuid});
                    console.log(" full name : "+me.state.full); 
                    $("#pic").attr("src", user.state.gravatar);

          myChat.on('message', (message) => {
                  console.log("message send mychat.on() method to send 
                      ");
                  renderMessage(message);
              });
              // when a user comes online, render them in the online list
              });

              bind our send button and return key to send message
              $('#sendMessage').on('submit', sendMessage)

          });

        };

        send a message to the Chat
        const sendMessage = () => {

            get the message text from the text input
            let message = $('#message-to-send').val().trim();

           if the message isn't empty
            if (message.length) {

                emit the message event to everyone in the Chat
                myChat.emit('message', {
                    text: message
                });

                // clear out the text input
                $('#message-to-send').val('');

            }

            // stop form submit from bubbling
            return false;

        };

        // render messages in the list
        const renderMessage = (message, isHistory = false) => {

            // use the generic user template by default
            let template = userTemplate;

            // if I happened to send the message, use the special 
               template for myself
            if (message.sender.uuid == me.uuid) {
                template = meTemplate;
            }

            let el = template({
                messageOutput: message.data.text,
                time: getCurrentTime(),
                user: message.sender.state
            });

            // render the message
            if(isHistory) {
              $('.chat-history ul').prepend(el); 
            } else {
              $('.chat-history ul').append(el); 
            }

            // scroll to the bottom of the chat
            scrollToBottom();
        };
        // end of render message 

        const privaterenderMessage = (message, isHistory = false) => {

            // use the generic user template by default
            let template = userTemplate;

            // if I happened to send the message, use the special 
           template for myself
            if (message.sender.uuid == me.uuid) {
                template = meTemplate;
            }

            let el = template({
                messageOutput: message.data.text,
                time: getCurrentTime(),
                user: message.sender.state
            });

        init();



        This is my Html Page to display the chat messages to the user
        <!DOCTYPE html>

<body>  
                <div class="container clearfix">
                    <div class="people-list" id="people-list">
                        <input type="text" id="search-user" 
        placeholder="Search user">
                         <ul class="list">
                        </ul>
                    </div>

                    <div class="chat">

                        <div class="chat-header clearfix">
                            <!-- <img src="" alt="avatar" /> -->
                            <div class="chat-about">
                                <div class="chat-with">ChatEngine Demo 
                    Chat</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                         here i am display ing globle chat messaage
                        <div class="chat-history " id="punlicLog">
                            <ul></ul>
                        </div>

                     here I will display the private chat message of the 
                      user
                        <div class="private-chat-history" id="privateLog" 

                style="display: none">
                            <ul></ul>
                        </div>

                        <span class="badge badge-pill badge-success" 
             id="typing" style="color:green"></span>

                   <form id="sendMessage" class="chat-message clearfix">
                  <input type="text" name="message-to-send" id="message- 
     to-send"
    placeholder="Type your message" rows="1"  
       onkeypress="keypress(event)"></input>
                            <input type="text" name="message-to-send" 
          class=
       "form-control" id="private-message-to-send" style="display: none" 
    placeholder
     ="Your message here..." onkeypress="keypress(event)">
                            <input type="submit" value="Send" >
                        </form>
                        <!-- end chat-message -->

                    </div>

                    <!-- end chat -->
                </div>
                <!-- end container -->

                 <!-- dynamic message display using javascript with the 
        pubnub -->
                 <script id="message-template" type="text/x-handlebars- 
      template">
                    <li class="clearfix">
                        <div class="message-data align-right">
                            <span class="message-data-time">{{time}}, 
             Today</span> &nbsp; &nbsp;
                            <span class="message-data-name"> 
      {{user.first}}</span> <i class="fa fa-circle me"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="message other-message float-right">
                            {{messageOutput}}
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </script>
                <script id="message-response-template" type="text/x- 
            handlebars- 
      template">
                    <li>
                        <div class="message-data">
                            <span class="message-data-name"><i class="fa 
           fa- 
        circle online"></i> {{user.first}}</span>
                            <span class="message-data-time">{{time}}, 
       Today</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="message my-message">
                            {{messageOutput}}
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </script>


                    <!-- // starting private message rendering -->


                    <script id="private-message-template" type="text/x- 
         handlebars-template" style="display: none">
                        <li class="clearfix">
                            <div class="message-data align-right">
                                <span class="message-data-time">{{time}}, 
          Today</span> &nbsp; &nbsp;
                          <span class="message-data-name">{{user.first}} 
        </span> <i class="fa fa-circle me"></i>
                            </div>
                         <div class="message other-message float-right">
                                {{messageOutput}}
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </script>
            <script id="private-message-response-template" type="text/x- 
        handlebars-template" >
                        <li>
                            <div class="message-data">
                         <span class="message-data-name"><i class="fa fa- 
         circle online"></i> {{user.first}}</span>
                                <span class="message-data-time">{{time}}, 
      Today</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="message my-message">
                                {{messageOutput}}
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </script>
                    <!-- // ending private message rendering -->


          <script id="person-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
                    {{#if state.full}}
                    <li class="clearfix" id="{{uuid}}">
                     <img src="" alt="photo"id="pic" style="height: 5px; 
       width: 5px"/>
                        <div class="about">
                            <div class="name">{{state.full}}</div>
                            <div class="status">
                              <i class="fa fa-circle online"></i> online
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    {{/if}}
                </script>
            </body>

      I want a private chat between the two users of the same channel and 
 multiple users also there and profile pic with gravatar also want`enter 
       code here.
```

Comment: Hi there, please look at this guide [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  specifically: just one topic per question (the profile pic is a separate question), use correct tags (Javascript, PubNub), show what you tried so far

Comment: Here are the doc links for both: 
[Private Chat docs](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/chat-engine/getting-started). 
[Avatar Docs](https://github.com/pubnub/chat-engine-gravatar).

Answer (score 1):

With PubNub and ChatEngine, you need to use separate channels for every chat room. You cannot have a private and a public chat that use the same channel. Every user can subscribe to many chats on many channels simultaneously. When you use the ChatEngine method to create a private chat, only the users who are involved can see the chat. The [ChatEngine "invite" for private chat documentation](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/chat-engine/reference/chat#invite) is here.

**Private Chat**

Some client's code

```
// one non-admin user running ChatEngine
let secretChat = new ChatEngine.Chat('unique-secret-channel');
secretChat.invite(adminUserObject);
```

The admin's client code

```
// This code goes in the admin client
me.direct.on('$.invite', (payload) => {
    let privChat = new ChatEngine.Chat(payload.data.channel, true);
});
```

**Gravatar**

This works when user's connect with email as part of their state object. Then you must initialize the gravatar plugin.  There is a [ChatEngine Gravatar Example here](https://github.com/pubnub/chat-engine-gravatar/blob/master/example.html).

```
// include the gravatar plugin script above    
ChatEngine.connect(uuid, { email: email@email.com });

// ...

for (let user of ChatEngine.users) {
    user.plugin(ChatEngine.plugin.gravatar());
    let div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = '<img src="' + user.state().gravatar + '" height="40" width="40"/>';
    // add html to the web page
}
```

Comment: Yes, I follow your guidelines but I am getting error when I execute the code,

Comment: please share any demo example because I am completely new to PUBNUB, only private chat and display profile pic is remaining, I stuck here please help me.   ERROR IS: 400 Invalid [Auth-key]  comming

Comment: Please reproduce with ChatEngine logging enabled and provide client logs: https://www.pubnub.com/docs/chat-engine/troubleshooting-guide

Comment: Have you set up a ChatEngine app on your PubNub account using the deploy button? https://www.pubnub.com/docs/chat-engine/getting-started#account-setup

Comment: I understood we have to create the separate channel for a private chat. but my requirement is we have a clinic and patient module  into that multiple clinics are there and for that specific clinic multiple patients are there, so tell me how do I manage private chat between specific clinic admin with their specific patient, consider in the feature 1000 clinic register then do I need to create 1000 channel in pubnub , is it possible to create 1000 channel if possible then how to do that runtime.

Comment: You can create any number of channels with PubNub, there is no limit. There is also no limit on ChatEngine chats because PubNub channels are the underlying technology. A single PubNub client can be subscribed to up to 20,000 channels at one time. A single ChatEngine user can be subscribed to up to ~1000 chats at one time. Again, you can create many, many more channels/chats, but individual users can subscribe to up to those maximums simultaneously.

Comment: Thanks, Adam I Got Idea to created private chat.  but now I am facing selecting one user out of online user list dynamically and start chatting to that particular user.  I am not getting this logic, please share any demo source code or at high-level Idea like how to select a user from the online list and start chatting with him.

Comment: Yes there are open source ChatEngine examples available on the PubNub tutorials page. Here is a demo for 1-to-1 chats with Vue.js and ChatEngine
Tutorial: https://www.pubnub.com/tutorials/chatengine/vuejs/chat-app/?devrel_gh=54098001
Demo: https://ajb413.github.io/chatengine-vue-chatbot-1to1/

Comment: Thanks, Adam for your support and I need one more help from you that is I want to retrieve the history of a specific user with time and day because when I fetch the history, messages are coming but for all the messages current time and day is displaying. please share code.

Comment: and aslo In private chat I am now facing issue that is when I send invitation from user to admin and at admin pannel there are multiple online users are there but same invitation is going to all the user when I click on it from online list of users. here my reqiurement is there will be multiple user and one admin,  admin can see list of all the users who are online but user can see only admin and when user send the message that message should go to the admin list of that sender user.

Comment: means here from admin side dynamic user selection is there and from the user side, he can see only admin, this is my requirement please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Please make a PubNub support ticket so the team can assist you further https://support.pubnub.com/support/tickets/new